# How do i save data from cloud firestore into a variable in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to save data from cloud firestore into a variable. My data is basically user data ( username , email , phone number )

I'm able to call the snapshot and print it but i can't save the data from firebase into a variable. I assume that this is because at the time of trying to assign the value the variable the data is not returned from firebase as yet.

```
DocumentSnapshot userObject ;
db.collection('users').where("email", isEqualTo: "jtent@mail.com").snapshots()
   .listen((data) =>data.documents.forEach((doc) => userObject = doc));

print(userObject);
```

i expected the userobject to store the snapshot retrieved from the database but instead it is null.

Comment: You're correct.  The Firestore API is asynchronous and the call to listen returns immediately before any data is available.  Your code is continuing before any results are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `async` method and `await` keyword.

```
 your_async_method () async {

     final documents = await db.collection('users').where("email", isEqualTo: "jtent@mail.com").getDocuments();
     final userObject = documents.documents.first.data;
     print(userObject);
 }
```

Comment: is it possible to listen data assign to variable?