# Flutter Firebase Firestore getting specific data and assigning to a variable and show them permanently

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need a help about how to get specific data from "FirebaseFirestore" and assign to a variable. Then i will write some if and else command etc. I searched for the solutions but nothing is worked for me. I have a 5 "Card" widget all are the same except their image and text ,this is where we are going to use our variable to.BTW data will come from field ("collection_name/document_name/fieldNo_1") Here is the Card widget code example:

```
Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/brick-pile.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I need to use the variable at the child "Text" Widget where it says "14". and Here is the full code of page:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
//Resource variables

return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: height * .5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: PlayerColorWGrey,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: PlayerColorWGrey,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: height * .5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 2.5),
            height: height * .2,
            width: width,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/stone-pile.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/brick-pile.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/sheep.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/wheat.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  elevation: 7.5,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/wood-pile.svg",
                            height: 75,
                            width: 50,
                            semanticsLabel: "Resource Card",
                          ),
                          Text("14",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontFamily: "Cairo",
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

thanks in advance

Edit 1 : I create a function and here is the code:

```
getData() {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("catanR")
    .doc('Player One White')
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  setState(() {
    wheat = value.data()!['wheat'];
    stone = value.data()!['stone'];
    brick = value.data()!['brick'];
    wood = value.data()!['wood'];
    sheep = value.data()!['sheep'];
  });
});
```

}

I think it works but I couldn't try it because as i said at the begining i will use these variables under the Text widget. So i should call funciton firstly and then function runs but all I need is these variables should be visible continuenly.

Edit 2: database structure for @Technical World:

[image]

Comment: Look into these similar threads. The solution in the below threads includes async, await and then keywords which might help.
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574264/flutter-firebase-database-variable-not-receiving-value-after-method 
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692806/how-do-i-save-data-from-cloud-firestore-into-a-variable-in-flutter 
[3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320438/flutter-getting-a-specific-firestore-document-data-and-store-it-into-a-string-va 
[4] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823096/flutter-get-single-data-from-firestore-cloud-to-variable

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Collection").get().then((value) {
//CARD 1
   String text1 = value.docs[0].get("text");
   String image1= value.docs[0].get("image");

//Card 2
   String text2 = value.docs[1].get("text");
   String image2= value.docs[1].get("image");
});
```

Comment: It didn't work when I defined a variable like "source" and assigned this code to it. I wrote "text1" and "resource.texte1" into the text widget (where it says "14"), none of them worked

Comment: and a little note: these variables are changing frequently so we need something like "setState"

Comment: please provide your database structure